# XSD having one element appear once between another repeating element (in any order)

Tags: xml

I have this problem in my XML-Schema where I want one element to repeat and another one that must appear exactly once between the repeating element or in any order.

In XML I want this to happen:

```
<elements>
   <second>Desc</second>
   <second>Desc1</second>
   <first>Desc</main>
   <second>Description</second>
</elements>
```

meaning there is no order where `second` appears 0 to `unbounded` and `first` exactly once.

My XML-Schema:

```
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
   <xs:element type="xs:string" name="second" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element type="xs:string" name="first"/>
</xs:choice>
```

This schema however allows both `first` and `second` to appear `unbounded` amount of times. I've tried setting `minOcurrs` and `maxOcurrs` of `first` to 1 but that doesn't change anything. Is there any way to achieve my desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the content model

```
sequence 
   A min=0 max=unbounded
   B
   A min=0 max=unbounded
```